# Маска для ввода денег

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения, inputmask

Всем добрый день, появилась необходимость в составлении маски для ввода денег.

Для поля ввода денег использую плагин [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html). Например есть сумма 50000, при вводе в поле по правилам маски `$('.money').mask('000 000 000 000 000', {reverse: true});` получается 50 000 что правильно, но иногда надо ввести точку, и тут возникает трудность. Нужна помощь в построении паттерна.

Попробовал сделать так:

```
$('.money').mask('ZZZXZZZXZZZXZZZ', {
    translation: {
      'Z': {
        pattern: /\d/, reverse: true
      },
      'X': {
        pattern: /\s|\./, reverse: true
      }
    }
});
```

Но это не решение, так как пробел всегда надо вводить в ручную. И это правило для 3-х значного числа, т.е 2.5 не написать. Нужно также учитывать что после точки не должно автоматически проставляться пробел.
Даже можно использовать какое нибудь кастомное решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил подключив плагин [Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask), использовал маску decimal и немного настроив.

Answer (score 1):

Там в документации к библиотеке много хороших примеров. Вот вариант решения для вашей задачи:

```js
jQuery('.money').mask('# ##0.00', {
  reverse: true,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.13/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<div>
  Money:
  <input class="money" type="text" />
</div>
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amhdutth/28/).

В данном варианте длина строки не задана жёстко, но предполагается наличие точки для десятичной части. Если точка стоит, все пробелы расставляются корректно.

Comment: К сожалению это не правильное решение данной задачи. Попробуйте ввести 5000 или 50000 даже без точки.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Сначала 5000 превращаются в 50.00, но при добавлении знаков перед точкой все разделители расставляются корректно (например, 5 000 000.00)

Comment: К сожалению это тоже не ответ на поставленную задачу, я тоже так пробовал сделать. Процитирую точка может быть, а может и не быть. По умолчанию её быть не должно. Т.е если ввести 50000 то должно быть 50 000, а не 500.00. В этом и заключается сложность. Если написать 50000.45555555 должно быть 50 000.45555555 . Т.е ограничение на кол-во чисел после точки тоже не должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

лучшее то что я использую
`pattern="(0\.((0[1-9]{1,5})|([1-9]{1,5}([0-9]{1,5})?)))|(([1-9]+[0-9]*)(\.([0-9]{1,5}))?)"`